# Hyperlinked word and web link finding using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, hyperlink

I have a text file which contains texts with a hyperlinked word as below:

This is my [website](https://www.prothomalo.com/) to read

Using python, is it possible to go to the links from those hyperlinked words and read them as text? I have already tried with `Requests` and `Scrapy` libraries but could find how to read hyperlinked words. These libraries deal directly with the weblink and can retrieve data from there, but not from the hyperlinked words.

Is there any library or any other way that can solve it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre]. In particular, please give us a clear example text so we know what you are working with.

Comment: what do you mean `hyperlinked word`? In HTML every word can be a hyperlink if it is in tag `<a href="...">word</a>` (in `anchor`) And you can get all anchors using `Beautifulsoup` or `lxml` after reading web page with `requests` - `soup.find_all("a")` and later use `.string` - `[item.string for item in soup_find_all("a")]`. In `scrapy` you can `select("a")`

Comment: Edited. I hope now the question is clarified.

Comment: in question (not in comment) you should show also what you tried - code, result and error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show your code so I don't understand what is your problem.

There is many tutorials and video tutorials which should explain it.

Using `beautifulsoup` you have to find all tags `<a>` (`anchors`) - `find_all("a")` (or `select('a')` which uses CSS selectors) and next get `.string` from every item separatelly - using `for`-loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.prothomalo.com/'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

#for item in soup.select("a"):
for item in soup.find_all("a"):
    text = item.string
    if text:  # skip links without text (ie. with images)
        print(text)
```

Result:

```
দেশে মৃত্যুদণ্ডের আসামিদের মধ্যে দরিদ্র মানুষ বেশি: গবেষণা
দেশে মৃত্যুদণ্ডপ্রাপ্তদের বেশির ভাগ দরিদ্র, স্বল্পশিক্ষিত ও সুবিধাবঞ্চিত মানুষ। বিচারিক আদালতের রায়ে মৃত্যুদণ্ডপ্রাপ্ত ৩৯ জনের মামলা নিয়ে করা গবেষণায় এমন তথ্য এসেছে।
নেইমারকে ছাড়াই ব্রাজিলের অলিম্পিক দল
আন্তর্জাতিক প্রতিযোগিতার জন্য খেলোয়াড় ছাড়ার বিষয়টি অবশ্য নির্দিষ্ট ওই খেলোয়াড়ের ক্লাবের ওপরও অনেকটা নির্ভর করে। তবে পিএসজির ফরোয়ার্ড নেইমারকে বাদ দিয়ে দল দেওয়ার সে রকম কোনো ব্যাখ্যা দেননি ব্রাজিল ...
শুক্র ও শনিবার বাড়তে পারে বৃষ্টিপাত
আবহাওয়া অফিস জানিয়েছে, শুক্রবার সন্ধ্যা ৬টা পর্যন্ত দেশের বিভিন্ন স্থানে অস্থায়ীভাবে দমকা হাওয়াসহ হালকা থেকে মাঝারি বৃষ্টি অথবা বজ্রসহ বিক্ষিপ্তভাবে মাঝারি থেকে ভারী বর্ষণ হতে পারে।
সপ্তাহের ব্যবধানে ঢাকায় রোগী বেড়েছে ৩ গুণের বেশি
ঢাকায় করোনা রোগী বেড়ে যাওয়া নিয়ে সরকারের রোগনিয়ন্ত্রণ সংস্থা আইইডিসিআরের পরামর্শক ডা. মুশতাক হোসেন বলেছেন, ঈদের পরপর সীমান্ত এলাকায় করোনার যে প্রকোপ শুরু হয়েছিল, তার প্রভাব পড়েছে রাজধানীসহ অন্যান্য ...
ঢাকায় করোনার ৬৮% নমুনায় ‘ভারতীয় ধরন’
ঢাকা থেকে সংগ্রহ করা ৬০টি নমুনার মধ্যে ৪১টিতেই ভারতীয় ধরন বা ‘ডেলটা ভেরিয়েন্ট’ পেয়েছে আন্তর্জাতিক উদরাময় গবেষণা কেন্দ্র, বাংলাদেশ (আইসিডিডিআরবি), যা মোট সংগৃহীত নমুনার ৬৮ শতাংশ। মে মাসের শেষ ও জুন ...
আম কোথায় বেশি হয়, লড়াইয়ে
চাঁপাইনবাবগঞ্জ ও নওগাঁ
কোরবানির পশুর হাটে ঢোকা-বের হওয়া ভিন্ন পথে
এবার হাজিদের জমজমের পানি বিতরণ করবে রোবট
সেবা বৃদ্ধিতে প্রযুক্তির প্রয়োগ বাড়াতে হবে: বিদ্যুৎ প্রতিমন্ত্রী
গোপন সঙ্গীর সঙ্গে জ্যাকুলিনের নতুন সংসার
নতুন বাড়ির একঝলক দেখালেন কারিনা
```

---

**EDIT:**

Or maybe you mean something different then text in link

ie. original `HTML` with tag `<a>` or link to next page `href`

```
for item in soup.find_all("a"):
    html = str(item)
    text = item.string
    link = item['href']
    if text:
        print('html:', html)
        print('text:', text)
        print('link:', link)
        print('---')
```

Full code (to make sure)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.prothomalo.com/'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

#for item in soup.select("a"):
for item in soup.find_all("a"):
    html = str(item)
    text = item.string
    link = item['href']
    if text:
        print('html:', html)
        print('text:', text)
        print('link:', link)
        print('---')
```

Result:

```
html: <a class="newsHeadline-m__title-link__1puEG" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-1" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/দেশে-মৃত্যুদণ্ডের-আসামিদের-মধ্যে-দরিদ্র-মানুষ-বেশি-গবেষণা">দেশে মৃত্যুদণ্ডের আসামিদের মধ্যে দরিদ্র মানুষ বেশি: গবেষণা</a>
text: দেশে মৃত্যুদণ্ডের আসামিদের মধ্যে দরিদ্র মানুষ বেশি: গবেষণা
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/দেশে-মৃত্যুদণ্ডের-আসামিদের-মধ্যে-দরিদ্র-মানুষ-বেশি-গবেষণা
---
html: <a data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-1" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/দেশে-মৃত্যুদণ্ডের-আসামিদের-মধ্যে-দরিদ্র-মানুষ-বেশি-গবেষণা">দেশে মৃত্যুদণ্ডপ্রাপ্তদের বেশির ভাগ দরিদ্র, স্বল্পশিক্ষিত ও সুবিধাবঞ্চিত মানুষ। বিচারিক আদালতের রায়ে মৃত্যুদণ্ডপ্রাপ্ত ৩৯ জনের মামলা নিয়ে করা গবেষণায় এমন তথ্য এসেছে।</a>
text: দেশে মৃত্যুদণ্ডপ্রাপ্তদের বেশির ভাগ দরিদ্র, স্বল্পশিক্ষিত ও সুবিধাবঞ্চিত মানুষ। বিচারিক আদালতের রায়ে মৃত্যুদণ্ডপ্রাপ্ত ৩৯ জনের মামলা নিয়ে করা গবেষণায় এমন তথ্য এসেছে।
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/দেশে-মৃত্যুদণ্ডের-আসামিদের-মধ্যে-দরিদ্র-মানুষ-বেশি-গবেষণা
---
html: <a class="newsHeadline-m__title-link__1puEG" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-2" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/sports/football/নেইমারকে-ছাড়াই-ব্রাজিলের-অলিম্পিক-দল">নেইমারকে ছাড়াই ব্রাজিলের অলিম্পিক দল</a>
text: নেইমারকে ছাড়াই ব্রাজিলের অলিম্পিক দল
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/sports/football/নেইমারকে-ছাড়াই-ব্রাজিলের-অলিম্পিক-দল
---
html: <a data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-2" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/sports/football/নেইমারকে-ছাড়াই-ব্রাজিলের-অলিম্পিক-দল">আন্তর্জাতিক প্রতিযোগিতার জন্য খেলোয়াড় ছাড়ার বিষয়টি অবশ্য নির্দিষ্ট ওই খেলোয়াড়ের ক্লাবের ওপরও অনেকটা নির্ভর করে। তবে পিএসজির ফরোয়ার্ড নেইমারকে বাদ দিয়ে দল দেওয়ার সে রকম কোনো ব্যাখ্যা দেননি ব্রাজিল ...</a>
text: আন্তর্জাতিক প্রতিযোগিতার জন্য খেলোয়াড় ছাড়ার বিষয়টি অবশ্য নির্দিষ্ট ওই খেলোয়াড়ের ক্লাবের ওপরও অনেকটা নির্ভর কর���। তবে পিএসজির ফরোয়ার্ড নেইমারকে বাদ দিয়ে দল দেওয়ার সে রকম কোনো ব্যাখ্যা দেননি ব্রাজিল ...
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/sports/football/নেইমারকে-ছাড়াই-ব্রাজিলের-অলিম্পিক-দল
---
html: <a class="newsHeadline-m__title-link__1puEG" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-3" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/শুক্র-ও-শনিবার-বাড়তে-পারে-বৃষ্টিপাত">শুক্র ও শনিবার বাড়তে পারে বৃষ্টিপাত</a>
text: শুক্র ও শনিবার বাড়তে পারে বৃষ্টিপাত
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/শুক্র-ও-শনিবার-বাড়তে-পারে-বৃষ্টিপাত
---
html: <a data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-3" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/শুক্র-ও-শনিবার-বাড়তে-পারে-বৃষ্টিপাত">আবহাওয়া অফিস জানিয়েছে, শুক্রবার সন্ধ্যা ৬টা পর্যন্ত দেশের বিভিন্ন স্থানে অস্থায়ীভাবে দমকা হাওয়াসহ হালকা থেকে মাঝারি বৃষ্টি অথবা বজ্রসহ বিক্ষিপ্তভাবে মাঝারি থেকে ভারী বর্ষণ হতে পারে।</a>
text: আবহাওয়া অফিস জানিয়েছে, শুক্রবার সন্ধ্যা ৬টা পর্যন্ত দেশের বিভিন্ন স্থানে অস্থায়ীভাবে দমকা হাওয়াসহ ��ালকা থেকে মাঝারি বৃষ্টি অথবা বজ্রসহ বিক্ষিপ্তভাবে মাঝারি থেকে ভারী বর্ষণ হতে পারে।
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/শুক্র-ও-শনিবার-বাড়তে-পারে-বৃষ্টিপাত
---
html: <a class="newsHeadline-m__title-link__1puEG" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-4" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/coronavirus/সপ্তাহের-ব্যবধানে-ঢাকায়-রোগী-বেড়েছে-৩-গুণের-বেশি">সপ্তাহের ব্যবধানে ঢাকায় রোগী বেড়েছে ৩ গুণের বেশি</a>
text: সপ্তাহের ব্যবধানে ঢাকায় রোগী বেড়েছে ৩ গুণের বেশি
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/coronavirus/সপ্তাহের-ব্যবধানে-ঢাকায়-রোগী-বেড়েছে-৩-গুণের-বেশি
---
html: <a data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-4" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/coronavirus/সপ্তাহের-ব্যবধানে-ঢাকায়-রোগী-বেড়েছে-৩-গুণের-বেশি">ঢাকায় করোনা রোগী বেড়ে যাওয়া নিয়ে সরকারের রোগনিয়ন্ত্রণ সংস্থা আইইডিসিআরের পরামর্শক ডা. মুশতাক হোসেন বলেছেন, ঈদের পরপর সীমান্ত এলাকায় করোনার যে প্রকোপ শুরু হয়েছিল, তার প্রভাব পড়েছে রাজধানীসহ অন্যান্য ...</a>
text: ঢাকায় করোনা রোগী বেড়ে যাওয়া নিয়ে সরকারের রোগনিয়ন্ত্রণ সংস্থা আইইডিসিআরের পরামর্শক ডা. মুশতাক হোসেন বলেছেন, ঈদের পরপর সীমান্ত এলাকায় করোনার যে প্রকোপ শুরু হয়েছিল, তার প্রভাব পড়েছে রাজধানীসহ অন্যান্য ...
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/coronavirus/সপ্তাহের-ব্যবধানে-ঢাকায়-রোগী-বেড়েছে-৩-গুণের-বেশি
---
html: <a class="newsHeadline-m__title-link__1puEG" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-5" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/coronavirus/ঢাকায়-করোনার-৬৮-নমুনায়-ভারতীয়-ধরন">ঢাকায় করোন���র ৬৮% নমুনায় ‘ভারতীয় ধরন’</a>
text: ঢাকায় করোনার ৬৮% নমুনায় ‘ভারতীয় ধরন’
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/coronavirus/ঢাকায়-করোনার-৬৮-নমুনায়-ভারতীয়-ধরন
---
html: <a data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-5" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/coronavirus/ঢাকায়-করোনার-৬৮-নমুনায়-ভারতীয়-ধরন">ঢাকা থেকে সংগ্রহ করা ৬০টি নমুনার মধ্যে ৪১টিতেই ভারতীয় ধরন বা ‘ডেলটা ভেরিয়েন্ট’ পেয়েছে আন্তর্জাতিক উদরাময় গবেষণা কেন্দ্র, বাংলাদেশ (আইসিডিডিআরবি), যা মোট সংগৃহীত নমুন���র ৬৮ শতাংশ। মে মাসের শেষ ও জুন ...</a>
text: ঢাকা থেকে সংগ্রহ করা ৬০টি নমুনার মধ্যে ৪১টিতেই ভারতীয় ধরন বা ‘ডেলটা ভেরিয়েন্ট’ পেয়েছে আন্তর্জাতিক উদরাময় গবেষণা কেন্দ্র, বাংলাদেশ (আইসিডিডিআরবি), যা মোট সংগৃহীত নমুনার ৬৮ শতাংশ। মে মাসের শেষ ও জুন ...
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/coronavirus/ঢাকায়-করোনার-৬৮-নমুনায়-ভারতীয়-ধরন
---
html: <a class="newsHeadline-m__title-link__1puEG" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-6" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/আম-কোথায়-বেশি-হয়-লড়াইয়��চাঁপাইনবাবগঞ্জ-ও-নওগাঁ">আম কোথায় বেশি হয়, লড়াইয়ে
চাঁপাইনবাবগঞ্জ ও নওগাঁ</a>
text: আম কোথায় বেশি হয়, লড়াইয়ে
চাঁপাইনবাবগঞ্জ ও নওগাঁ
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/আম-কোথায়-বেশি-হয়-লড়াইয়েচাঁপাইনবাবগঞ্জ-ও-নওগাঁ
---
html: <a class="newsHeadline-m__title-link__1puEG" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-7" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/কোরবানির-পশুর-হাটে-ঢোকা-বের-হওয়া-ভিন্ন-পথে">কোরবানির পশুর হাটে ঢোকা-বের হওয়া ভিন্ন পথে</a>
text: কোরবানির পশুর হাটে ঢোকা-বের হওয়া ভ��ন্ন পথে
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/কোরবানির-পশুর-হাটে-ঢোকা-বের-হওয়া-ভিন্ন-পথে
---
html: <a class="newsHeadline-m__title-link__1puEG" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-10" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/world/asia/এবার-হাজিদের-জমজমের-পানি-বিতরণ-করবে-রোবট">এবার হাজিদের জমজমের পানি বিতরণ করবে রোবট</a>
text: এবার হাজিদের জমজমের পানি বিতরণ করবে রোবট
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/world/asia/এবার-হাজিদের-জমজমের-পানি-বিতরণ-করবে-রোবট
---
html: <a class="newsHeadline-m__title-link__1puEG" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-11" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/capital/সেবা-বৃদ্ধিতে-প্রযুক্তির-প্রয়োগ-বাড়াতে-হবে-বিদ্যুৎ-প্রতিমন্ত্রী">সেবা বৃদ্ধিতে প্রযুক্তির প্রয়োগ বাড়াতে হবে: বিদ্যুৎ প্রতিমন্ত্রী</a>
text: সেবা বৃদ্ধিতে প্রযুক্তির প্রয়োগ বাড়াতে হবে: বিদ্যুৎ প্রতিমন্ত্রী
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/bangladesh/capital/সেবা-বৃদ্ধিতে-প্রযুক্তির-প্রয়োগ-বাড়াতে-হবে-বিদ্যুৎ-প্রতিমন্ত্রী
---
html: <a class="newsHeadline-m__title-link__1puEG" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-12" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/entertainment/bollywood/গোপন-সঙ্গীর-সঙ্গে-জ্যাকুলিনের-নতুন-সংসার">গোপন সঙ্গীর সঙ্গে জ্যাকুলিনের নতুন সংসার</a>
text: গোপন সঙ্গীর সঙ্গে জ্যাকুলিনের নতুন সংসার
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/entertainment/bollywood/গোপন-সঙ্গীর-সঙ্গে-জ্যাকুলিনের-নতুন-সংসার
---
html: <a class="newsHeadline-m__title-link__1puEG" data-tracking-action="Click" data-tracking-category="Component One" data-tracking-label="Position-13" href="https://www.prothomalo.com/entertainment/bollywood/নতুন-বাড়ির-একঝলক-দেখালেন-কারিনা">নতুন বাড়ির একঝলক দেখালেন কারিনা</a>
text: নতুন বাড়ির একঝলক দেখালেন কারিনা
link: https://www.prothomalo.com/entertainment/bollywood/নতুন-বাড়ির-একঝলক-দেখালেন-কারিনা
---
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers. But my problem was a bit different which I could not explain and I apologize for that. I had login into an email, read the emails one by one and then find the links inside the email. To login into the email, I used IMAP so I did not have any request object. However, using href from the beautifulsoup I was able to find the links. I will share the base code soon so that it can be helpful for any other person.